# How do I change the icon size of the left dock in Debian?

Tags: debian, gnome3, desktop

I want to change it to smaller. I remember I can change it in the settings→display. However, I can't find it anywhere.

[image]

I am using Debian 9.5 on VMware.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a desktop Debian user, but Ubuntu one, Gnome based.

In Ubuntu 18.4.1 LTS (bionic), go the the Settings app, in the Dock panel there is a Icon size slider.
Cheers

Screenshot from **Ubuntu 18.4.1 LTS**

[image]

Screenshot from **Ubuntu 20.10**
[image]

Comment: I see no "Dock" panel in Debian control center with GNOME 3.

Comment: @RomanRiabenko I'm now on Ubuntu `bullseye/sid` (aka Ubuntu 20.10). In the Setting app, the left menu entry is called `Appearance`.

Comment: I don't see "Appearance" panel in the settings in Debian Bullseye either.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install this package : [Offical package in Debian site](https://packages.debian.org/sid/gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock)

`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock` .

Then reload your shell to `Alt+F2 r Enter`.

Open `tweak tool` and see the `extension` `Dash To Dock` to modify your aspects.

[Developer GitHub site](https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/download.html)

**Icon size limit** to change icon size

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can change the size by using this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dash-max-icon-size 64
```

Comment: I've just tried that on Debian. It complains that there is no such schema "org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock".